# Powerpoint syntax does not run

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have the following code:

```
Sub ppt()

Dim pptapp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim slide As PowerPoint.slide
Dim shape As PowerPoint.shape

Dim var1 As String

Set pptapp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
pptapp.Visible = True

Set ppt = pptapp.Presentations.Open("X:\SSC_HR\SENS\Bedrijfsbureau\Rapportages\SENS      referenten rapportage\Nieuwe ref rap template\SENS referent rapportage januari 2014.pot")
Set slide = ppt.Slides(1)
Set shape = slide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 100, 500, 100, 100)

var = InputBox("Insert weeknumber")

With shape

.TextFrame.TextRange = "Update call Jeroen van Breda Vriesman/Ton van der Linden" & vbNewLine & var1 & vbNewLine & "Tel nr: +31 (0)10 - 299 1002  code 59790989 "
.Line.Visible = True
.Width = 200
.Height = 200
.TextEffect.FontSize = 12

End With

With ppt
.SaveAs "C:\Documents and Settings\aa471714\Desktop\" & "SENS referentenrapporge - week" & var1
.Close
```

End With

End Sub

I have two problems with it

1. I try to arrange the font size using this statement

   .TextEffect.FontSize = 12

But this does not work.Anybody a clue what goes wrong here. If I run it without this line all goes well.

1. If I run it now I have to insert a number. But then that number does not show up in the file. I already tried to change the dim to

   Dim var1 As Number

I get an error that the user defined type is not defined. Anybody know what goes wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Instead, use this:

```
With shape

.TextFrame.TextRange = "Update call Jeroen van Breda Vriesman/Ton van der Linden" & vbNewLine & var1 & vbNewLine & "Tel nr: +31 (0)10 - 299 1002  code 59790989 "
.Line.Visible = True
.Width = 200
.Height = 200
.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 12

End With
```

And you'd want to do

Dim var1 as Long or some other numeric type if it's to hold a number; otherwise, as String